# Using Google Map API v2 drawing a route from current location to destination location in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to draw a driving route from current location to destination location with the help of this link
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/driving-route-from-my-location-to-destination-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/

Am getting a route while clicking a map but i want to give a destination location manually once map is loaded automatically route will be show how to do this pls send a code..

Comment: There is a Java API for Google Directions API which parses the JSON for you and give you some objects that can be drawn easily in the Map: https://github.com/perezdidac/google-directions-api

Comment: what are the codes i want to add in my application pls tell me sir?

Comment: Two great answers were given and none were accepted. Downvoted until one is accepted.

Comment: hey man both the answers are not correct but i done with the help of different concept stupid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this code:

1) Call google map service to get the route information:

```
StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString
                .append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?sensor=true");
        urlString.append("&origin=");// from
        urlString.append(curLocation.getLatitude());
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(curLocation.getLongitude());
        urlString.append("&destination=");// to
        urlString.append(carPark.getLat());
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(carPark.getLng());
        Log.d("xxx", "URL=" + urlString.toString());

        aq.ajax(urlString.toString(), JSONObject.class, this,
                "gmapCallback");
```

2) Parse the response string from google.

```
public GeoPoint[] parseRoute(String content) {
    Document doc = null;
    GeoPoint[] route = null;
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes()));

        if (doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").getLength() > 0) {
            // String path =
            // doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").item(0).getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeName();
            String path = doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection")
                    .item(0).getFirstChild().getFirstChild()
                    .getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
            Log.d("xxx", "path=" + path);
            String[] pairs = path.split(" ");
            String[] lngLat;
            // lngLat[0]=longitude
            // lngLat[1]=latitude
            // lngLat[2]=height
            route = new GeoPoint[pairs.length];
            GeoPoint gp;
            for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
                lngLat = pairs[i].split(",");
                gp = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1]) * 1E6),
                        (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0]) * 1E6));
                route[i] = gp;
                Log.d("xxx", "pair:" + pairs[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Utils.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
    }
    return route;
}
```

Comment: can u pls send a full code.? am done drawing route from current location to destination location after map loaded if i clicked certain location it will show a route from current to destination but once map is loaded it will show driving route from current to destination how to do this?

Comment: I think it's enough for you,  aq.ajax(urlString.toString(), JSONObject.class, this,
                "gmapCallback");  is from AQuery library, it just start a http request.

Comment: where i want to add this two codes?

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to achieve that,

1.)Use built  in [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

2.)Use Google [api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Just pass your address in any of the two methods and get the latitude and longitude of that corresponding address and pass it with your current location latitude and longitude to draw a route.